# How to find and replace a line that has reserved characters and spaces

Tags: batch-file, passwords, complexity-theory

I'm new at batches.
I'm trying to edit a line in a file using batch.
However, the line contains spaces and a reserved character (the `=` sign)
Basically, I want to change `PasswordComplexity = 1` to `PasswordComplexity = 0`, which is in a file named `export.cfg`
All ideas appreciated, here is what I have now:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("export.cfg") DO (
set "line=%%a" & echo !line:(PasswordComplexity = 1)=(PasswordComplexity = 0)!
)>>"import.cfg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, equal signs `=` cannot be **simply** replaced with just native Windows solutions.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561827/891976

If the line containing PasswordComplexity only has the single digit, you can do something like this:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("export.cfg") do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "found=false"
    for /f "delims=" %%B in (echo %%A^|find "PasswordComplexity = 1") do set "found=true"
    if !found!==true (
        echo !line:1=0!
    ) else (
        echo !line!
    )
)>>"import.cfg"

endlocal
```

Also note that whenever using special characters literally outside of quotation marks, they must be escaped.  See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: Nice try, but wrong! An opending bracket need no escape, the closing does, but the equal can't be escaped in a repalce expression. An equal sign can't be replaced this way