# How to get a substring with a special character when use enabledelayedexpansion in CMD?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, command, prompt

i want to rename one or more files using cmd. but a lot of this files have a special character.
example:

```
DCIM_!01.jpeg
DCIM_&01.jpeg
DCIM_=01.jpeg
```

normally, we can use this value "^" to set a especial string as simple text. but when set enabledelayedexpansion the string don't is settable

```
set /p mystring=!
```

the users define string value: !, &, = and others...

the file name is defined by other variable "FOR" to search it in the folders

so string "File" value is "DCIM_!01.jpeg"

Command to change the file name:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set new_filename=!file:^%mystring%=0!
echo !new_filename!
```

the results on prompt is:

```
:=0
file:=0
DCIM_!01.jpeg
DCIM_01.jpeg
```

I want to rewrite "!" to "0":

```
DCIM_001.jpeg
```

when i don't use a special string the command works for me

Comment: Is there any reason not to just `disabledelayedexpansion`? That way, `ren "DCIM_%mystring:~0,1%01.jpeg" "DCIM_001.jpeg"` is perfectly safe even with characters like `&`. (cannot handle `"` but filenames cannot contain quotes anyways)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick demonstration code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "TempDir=%TEMP%\%~n0"
if exist "%TempDir%\" goto CreateFiles
md "%TempDir%" && goto CreateFiles
echo Failed to create temporary directory:
echo/
echo "%TempDir%"
echo/
pause
rem The command endlocal is executed implicit by cmd.
exit /B

:CreateFiles
pushd "%TempDir%"
echo DCIM_!01.jpeg>"%TempDir%\DCIM_!01.jpeg"
echo DCIM_^&02.jpeg>"%TempDir%\DCIM_&02.jpeg"
echo DCIM_=03.jpeg>"%TempDir%\DCIM_=03.jpeg"
echo DCIM_%%04.jpeg>"%TempDir%\DCIM_%%04.jpeg"
echo DCIM_)05.jpeg>"%TempDir%\DCIM_)05.jpeg"

:UserPrompt
set "MyString="
set /P "SearchString=String to replace: "
rem Has the user not entered a string?
if not defined SearchString goto UserPrompt
rem Remove all double quotes.
set "SearchString=%SearchString:"=%"
rem Is there no search string left?
if not defined SearchString goto UserPrompt
rem Replace all exclamation marks by vertical bars.
set "SearchString=%SearchString:!=|%"
echo/

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "*.jpeg" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    set "RealName=%%I"
    set "FileName=%%I"
    rem Replace in file name all exclamation marks by vertical bars.
    call set "FileName=%%FileName:!=|%%"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NewName=!FileName:%SearchString%=0!"
    if not "!NewName!" == "!FileName!" echo ren "!RealName!" "!NewName!"
    endlocal
)

echo/
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /M "Run once more (Y/N):"
if errorlevel 2 goto UserPrompt

popd
rd /Q /S "%TempDir%"
endlocal
```

You can see that the demo code does not work for search strings containing `=`. There must be special code used for replacing equal signs or a different script interpreter is used like PowerShell.
See also: [How to replace “=” (equal signs) and a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556676/)

The solution for exclamation marks is replacing in search string each `!` by `|` and do the same for the current file name before enabling delayed environment variable expansion. A file name cannot contain a vertical bar as described by Microsoft on documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). So it is safe to replace all `!` by `|` in a file name before doing the string substitution with enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

The replacement of `!` by `|` in the **FOR** loop must be done by referencing the environment variable `FileName` with `%%`. The reason is that the command line

```
call set "FileName=%%FileName:!=|%%"
```

is processed by `cmd.exe` before execution of command **FOR** to

```
call set "FileName=%FileName:!=|%"
```

The command **CALL** is used to force a second parsing and processing of this command line by `cmd.exe` on each iteration of the loop to really do the character replacement on current string value assigned to environment variable `FileName`.

See also:

- [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Then delayed expansion can be enabled to do the string replacement on already slightly modified file name and run the command **REN** on file name really modified by the string replacement with real name of current file and new file name. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

The demonstration code does not really run the command **REN**, it just outputs how **REN** would be executed on removing command **ECHO**.

Comment: thank you very much.  with your example i can create my batch file working full. thanks so. i left this example of my batch to you see, but idon't understand as you about this scripts. https://filebin.net/vh355pwy1uau3xpf/BatchExample_working_test.bat?t=452p3tp6