# Batch file assignment woes

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following simple batch file doesn't work as expected. It's meant to accept an argument, and if none is supplied, it uses a default value ("default", in this case).

Instead, if there is no argument supplied, it assigns an empty string to the variable Arg.

Test.bat:

```
@echo off
set Arg=%1
if "%Arg%"=="" (
    set Arg=Default
    echo No Arg, so use default value=%Arg%
) else (
    echo Arg=%Arg%
)
pause
```

The output of Test.bat is:

```
No Arg, so use default value=
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@echo off
set Arg=%1
if not defined arg set Arg=Default&echo No Arg, so use default
echo Arg=%Arg%
```

The problem is that within a block (parenthesisied series of statements) variables are resolved at PARSE time - before the instructions are executed.

```
@echo off
set Arg=%1
if not defined arg set Arg=Default&call echo No Arg, so use default=%%arg%%
echo Arg=%Arg%
```

if you really want the default to be displayed on the report line.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then `!Arg!` instead of `%Arg%` within the block. And read `help set` which explains all this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] (
   set Arg=Default
) else (
   set Arg=%1
)
@echo Arg=%Arg%
```

Reference: [How to check command line parameter in ".bat" file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953170/how-to-check-command-line-parameter-in-bat-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set arg=default
if not "%~1"=="" set "arg=%~1"
echo arg is ""%arg%"
```