# Batch file error handle

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, command-line, parameter-passing

I have batch file that execute my php script, but I dont know how to handle the empty argument, can you help me?

this is my batch script

```
echo off
set phppath=%1
set resultfolder=%2
set jsonfile=%3
shift
shift
shift

set PHP_HOME=%phppath%
set PATH=%PATH%;%PHP_HOME%
echo Set PHP_HOME in "%phppath%"
echo Locate result in folder "%resultfolder%"
echo JSON file is "%jsonfile%"


pause;
php -f cxense_json_to_xml.php %resultfolder% %jsonfile%
```

Comment: [read me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953170/how-to-check-command-line-parameter-in-bat-file)

Comment: @ShawnMehan - wrong shell environment, that won't help at all.

Comment: Which argument could be empty and what exactly do you want to do if one of them is missing? Is there a kind of default value or do you want to output an error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set phppath=%1
set resultfolder=%2
set jsonfile=%3
set PHP_HOME=%phppath%
set PATH=%PATH%;%PHP_HOME%
echo Set PHP_HOME in "%phppath%"
echo Locate result in folder "%resultfolder%"
echo JSON file is "%jsonfile%"
php -f cxense_json_to_xml.php %resultfolder% %jsonfile%
Pause
```

And the batch would have to be started like this:

```
Batch.bat "path to PHP" "path to result folder" "name of jsonfile"
```

there is no semicolon after pause.