# How can I store a NULL ASCII character (nul) in a variable with a Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, null, ascii

Following the post [How can I write a null ASCII character (nul) to a file with a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2730732) there are indeed methods to write an ASCII NULL character (nul) to a file with a batch script.

However, I cannot find a way to store a NULL character to a variable.

Supposing the file `null.nil` contains a single NULL character, redirecting it into `set /P` does not seem work, the variable appears empty:

```
< "null.nil" set /P NULL=
set NULL
```

`for /F` does not appear to work either as it seems to dismiss every NULL character it encounters. Relying on the same file `null.nil`, the following results in an empty variable:

```
for /F %%S in ('type "null.nil"') do set NULL=%%S
set NULL
```

Changing the `set` syntax to `set "NULL=%%S"` or to `set NULL=^%%S` does not change anything, although the command line `type "null.nil"` does echo the NULL character (on my Windows 10 x64 machine; redirect `type` output to a file and view it with a hex. editor).

So how can I set a variable to a single NULL character? The NULL character can either be taken from a file (like `null.nil`) or generated by some smart hack, but I do not want it to be embedded in the batch file directly.

Comment: Just a guess... I'd suspect that internally env. variables are handled as null-terminated strings, and since a string containing nothing but a null char is empty (nothing as far as content), and setting an env. var to nothing clears it, you're going to have an issue here. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right, @KenWhite; I just found a post here that confirms your reasonable suspicion: [Setting environment variables for a specific run of a specific process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092538)

Comment: If you somehow managed to `set a variable to a single NULL character` how do you foresee you could *use* that variable?

Comment: I even tried to create a python 3 script and put a NULL char in an env. var, but child cmd wouldn't take it: undefined. So Ken White is probably right. It's like  trying to put a null char in a C-string.

Comment: @dxiv, since environment variables turned out to be stored as null-terminated, it is of course not possible to read them; I was not aware about the storage format when I asked the question...

Comment: Why downvote? do you confuse a negative answer like "it is not possible" with downvoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the page [Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx) of Microsoft's MSDN Library and also to the post [Setting environment variables for a specific run of a specific process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13092538), the environment block is stored in a NULL-terminated block of NULL-terminated strings -- here quickly illustrated in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation:

> ```
> environment-block = { variable-definition } , null-char ;
> variable-definition = variable-name , '=' , variable-value , null-char ;
> ```

Due to this storage format it is not possible to store a NULL character into an environment variable. Even if one managed to get a NULL written to the environment block it could not ever be read again.